# How to get the string form of pyparsing keyword class

Tags: pyparsing

I have been working on a DSL using pyparsing.

I have a couple of keywords. The doumentation on pyparsing keyword class is found at http://packages.python.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.Keyword-class.html

I defined them as

```
this = Keyword("this", caseless=cl)
that = Keyword("that", caseless=cl)
```

I have a dictionary where the above keywords translate into numbers:

```
helper_dict = {"this":-1, "that":1}
```

the problem I am facing is that I am not able to get a consistent string representation for them. When I try str(this), it comes with the quotes. So I can not really use the dictionary without getting a key error. I mean I get a `KeyError` when I try any of the following:

```
helper_dict[this]
helper_dict[this.__str__()]
helper_dict[str(this)]
```

How can I get a proper string representation

I looked at both the documentation for keyword and the super class of keyword and I can not figure out which function is actually supposed to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` and `that` are not strings, they are pyparsing expressions defined using strings, but they are not strings. As for `helper_dict`, you have defined the keys using the strings "this" and "that". You will get back strings from the `this` and `that` expressions after they have parsed some input containing their defining input strings.

Here is some console experimenting to show you how this works:

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>> this = Keyword("this", caseless=True)
>>> that = Keyword("that", caseless=True)
>>> result = (this|that).parseString("This")
>>> print result
['this']
```

Note that Keyword always returns a consistent token in terms of upper/lower case, regardless of the input string's case. CaselessLiteral and caseless Keyword always return tokens in the case of their defining strings, not the case of the input string.

```
>>> print result[0]
this
>>> print type(result[0])
<type 'str'>
```

The parsed data is returned in a ParseResults object, which supports list, dict, and object-style addressing. Here the 0'th element is a string, the string "this". You can use this string to match the key "this" defined in helper_dict:

```
>>> helper_dict = {"this":1, "that":-1}
>>> helper_dict[result[0]]
1
```

Or define a parse action to do this substitution for you at parse time (replaceWith is a helper method defined in pyparsing:

```
>>> this.setParseAction(replaceWith(1))
"this"
>>> print (this | that).parseString("This")[0]
1
```

-- Paul